# Drag Drop Problems of react-dnd library - nested drop target

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-redux, react-dnd

Recently, the project Im using is lib react-dnd. Im in trouble w the bug so plz help me.

BUG: Drop both top n bottom of component.

Describe: In base I have 5 dragsources, 2 droptargets. when base have no component, component will render together with 2 droptargest on top n bottom. 
=> when users use hover to 2 droptargets up and bottom, drop will be in that situation.
A kind of tree view

TROUBLE;  Hover can not detech child droptargets below ( target base still on top), so I can not drop it

To make it clearer, checking attached photos 
Thank you so much for taking your time and consideration.

Please let me know If i go wrong in rules of how to post question on StackOverFlow.

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccWkf.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: anybody here to help me ?

Comment: I don't think you can expect help when you posted pictures of code instead of the actual code...how is someone going to be able to help without having to retype all that code out?